# Calculate Years after Hire from same table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement to calculate year of hire from a table, now sure how to achieve it

Below is case

[image]

and the Output should look like below based on the action column,

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks !

Comment: Are you going to have people who leave the company and rejoin at a later date? If so, do you want the date from the most recent hire? Or, do you want the total time at the company? Or, do you want the total time since they were first hiired?

Comment: Yes there will be cases when People will leave the company and then join back again. In this case we would want the latest hire date, however the Person Number will always be same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MAX` with a `CASE` and `GROUP By` the `person_number`:

```sql
SELECT person_number,
       MONTHS_BETWEEN(
         SYSDATE,
         MAX( CASE WHEN action = 'HIRE' THEN effective_start_date END )
       ) / 12 AS Number_of_years
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY person_number;
```

So for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( person_number, effective_start_date, action ) AS
SELECT 100, DATE '2000-07-01', 'HIRE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, DATE '2002-01-02', 'MANAGER CHANGE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, DATE '2014-06-20', 'PROMOTION' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, DATE '2019-10-10', 'LOCATION CHANGE' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> PERSON_NUMBER |                           NUMBER_OF_YEARS
> ------------: | ----------------------------------------:
>           100 | 19.81079360190163281561131023496614894467
> ```

If you want full years then you can use `TRUNC` or `FLOOR` on the number of years and if you want to round to the nearest full year then use `ROUND`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b2aa32d2ed684281672d2a4784b54447)*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the date column is really a date and not an absurd string, you can just filter:

```
select floor(months_between(sysdate, effective_start_date) / 12)
from t
where action = 'hire';
```